# Ruby on Rails Directory Path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to print Ruby on Rails complete url in my application. in details

with RAILS_ROOT I m getting a url like this

D:/projects/rails_app/projectname/data/default.jpg

But for my application I need a path like this

http://localhost:3000/data/default.jpg

Please help me to solve this issue. I am using Rails 2

Thanks

Comment: Could you answer your question then, and accept it later?

Comment: no  mliebelt..... the problem was wasting my time for long time ... so I just answer it .... I just thought that will help anyone ...

Answer (score -1):

Today we use `URI`. Simply `require` the library and you will be able to parse your current dynamic and static URI any way you please. For example I have a function that can read URI parameters like so...

---

`#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/helpers/application_helper.rb` (The literal path string of the file depicted below)

```
def read_uri(parameter)
  require 'uri'
  @raw_uri = URI.parse(request.original_fullpath)
  @uri_params_raw = @raw_uri.query
  if @uri_params_raw =~ /\=/
    @uri_vars = @uri_params_raw.split('=')
    return @uri_vars[parameter]
  end
  return false
end
```

This should split all URI parameters into an array that gives the requested (numeric) "parameter".
I believe that simply the `URI.parse(request.original_fullpath)` should work for you.
I come from using a minimum of rails 4.2.6 with this method so, I hope it works for anyone who might view this later on. Oh, and just as a disclaimer: I wasn't so wise to rails at the time of posting this.